# Can an open interval $]a,b[$ be decomposed in homeomorphic parts? (And what about a closed interval $[a,b]$?)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology

Let $ a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $ a<b $.

1. Is it possible to find disjoint subsets $ P_1, P_2 $ of the **open interval** ]a,b[ that are homeomorphic (w.r.t. their "ordinary" subspace topologies) such that $ P_1 \dot\cup P_2 = ]a,b[ $?
2. Is it possible for the **closed interval** $ [a,b] $?

I am pretty sure that the answer to both questions is no (as opposed to for the half-open interval $ [a,b[ $). There is probably a very easy proof but I am having a hard time finding it. So any hints to get me on track are much appreciated. :-)

*Thanks for the answer to (1.) @Greg Martin. **Question (2.) is still open.***

Comment: I first thought I proved that there is no such decomposition for the closed interval $ [a,b] $ by assuming a homeomorphism $ f \colon P_1 \longrightarrow P_2 $ and then looking at the continuous function $ g \colon [a,b] \longrightarrow [a,b] $ that maps $ x $ to $ f(x) $ in case $ x \in P_1 $ and to  $ f^{-1}(x) $ in case $ x \in P_2 $. This would have yielded a contradiction since $ g $  would have a fixed point. But then I realized that $ g $ (which I "glued together" from $ f $ and $ f^{-1} $) need not be continuous at all. Right?

Answer (score 5):

The answer is yes in the first case at least.

For example, consider the following two subsets of $(0,1)$:
\begin{align*}
P_1 &= [\tfrac12,1) \cup [\tfrac18,\tfrac14) \cup [\tfrac1{32},\tfrac1{16}) \cup \cdots \\
P_2 &= [\tfrac14,\tfrac12) \cup [\tfrac1{16},\tfrac18) \cup [\tfrac1{64},\tfrac1{32}) \cup \cdots \\
\end{align*}
Then $P_1$ and $P_2$ form a partition of $(0,1)$, and they are homeomorphic—the map $f(x)=2x$ from $P_2$ to $P_1$ is a homeomorphism, for example.